# Getting error when adding wss 3.0 Content database through stsadm commands

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, wss-3.0

I have backup of a WSS 3.0 content database and trying to attach to it in dev environment (WSS 3.0). I am getting the following error

> The operation failed because an index or statistics with name
>   'RecycleBin_TransactionId' already exists on table 'RecycleBin'.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

as this is you dev environment, it is safe to drop the Index and then try to re attach it.You can run this command in SQL management studio against your DB

```
DROP INDEX RecycleBin_TransactionId ON RecycleBin
```

This error message appears when you try to create an index while another index with the same name already exists. I know you are just trying to attach the Content DB But i think it is sharepoint which is trying to create new index using the same name.

Comment: When I am trying to drop the index getting the following error. "Cannot drop index 'RecycleBin_TransactionId' because it enforces the full-text key for table or indexed view 'RecycleBin'."